# Regular expression: Search/replace

Tags: regex

I have a SQL-file with 8.500 lines. I need to search/replace the beginning of the lines and replace for the first four fields:

```
"(239, 100, NULL, NULL, " to "(239$100$NULL$NULL$"
```

Unfortunately some of the lines doesn't use "NULL":

```
"(179, 99, 0, '', "
```

I never use the fields 3 and 4. I don't know the reason why the null-values are written differently, but i suppose there are three variations: NULL, 0 and ''.

The purpose is to use the $ as a separator in Excel.

Comment: What would be the output for the second example? What language did you're running?

Comment: If these are rows in a database, wouldn't it be better to use proper database access methods (e. g. SQL, the database system's API, etc.) to manipulate and format the data rather than falling back to horrible regular expression hackery?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure this can be done in a smarter way, but I'm not expereienced. I have recognized a few disadvantages (for me) by using he available export formats (CSV etc.).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you'll be doing the replacements in a text file. You can do this:

Search: `^\((\d+),\s*(\d+)(?:[^,]*,){3}`

Replace: `($1$$2$NULL$NULL$`

In [the online demo](http://regex101.com/r/dP1aZ8/7), see the substitutions at the bottom.

**Explanation**

- The `^` anchor asserts that we are at the beginning of the string
- `\(` matches the opening parenthesis
- `(\d+)` captures the first digits to Group
- `,` matches the first comma
- `\s*` matches optional white-space
- `(\d+)` captures the second set of digits to Group 2
- `(?:[^,]*,){3}` eats up anything up to the 3rd next comma
- we replace with Group 1, `$`, Group 2, `$`, `NULL$NULL$`

Comment: Thank you to all. The search patterns suggested works fine, but the replace are written as as string - not as an interpretated output: "($1$$$2$$NULL$$NULL,".

I use Textwrangler for Mac. In search/replace i check "Grep" and fill out the search-/replace fields.

Comment: Well this is a regex question, and you need an editor that has decent regex support... I read on another thread that `Textmate` has decent regex. Otherwise, would you like a Perl one-liner? I could make you one that you run from the terminal, that's another option. Also note that in some editors `$1` is not used, `\1` is used instead, so you may want to give that a try.

Comment: \1 instead of $1 dis the job. Now everything is working. Thank you very much.

Comment: Oh, just one more thing: is it possible to add a code that tells that it's the only in beginning of a line? I recognized a few occurrencies of lines where the pattern is found in other places too.

"beginning of line" + \((\d+),\s*(\d+)(?:[^,]*,){3}

Comment: Hey I had added the thing you wanted at the beginning of the line. Why did you unaccept the answer?

Comment: Oooops, my mistake. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

The following regex will match all possible combinations:

```
^"\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(NULL|\d+|''),\s+(NULL|\d+|''), "
     ---      ---      -----------      -----------
    Number   Number  NULL or 0 or ''  NULL or 0 or ''
```

Answer (score 0):

Sublime Text can do it for you without writing any code. Simply paste your SQL in it, press Ctrl-H, check Regular Expresstion, then replace

```
^\((\d+),\s*(\d+),[^,]+,[^,]+,
```

with

```
($1$$$2$$NULL$$NULL,
```

You can also test it on http://jsfiddle.net/JohnnyWorker/u6xMc/light/ that I wrote (remember to check Global and Multiline) but I don't recommend you to paste your 8.500 lines here. This jsFiddle is just for testing your patterns.